# Analysis I, can Tao's construction of the integers be further simplified?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, integers, peano-axioms

In chapter 4 of Analysis I by Terence Tao, we have the following note about the set theoretic construction of the integers:

> In the language of set theory, what we are doing here is starting with the space N × N of ordered
> pairs (a, b) of natural numbers. Then we place an equivalence relation ∼ on these pairs by declaring
> (a, b) ∼ (c, d) iff a + d = c + b. The set-theoretic interpretation of the symbol a — b is that it is the
> space of all pairs equivalent to (a, b): a — b := {(c, d) ∈ N × N : (a, b) ∼ (c, d)}; the existence of
> the set Z = {a — b : (a, b) ∈ N × N} of integers then follows from two applications of the axiom
> of replacement. However, this interpretation plays no role in how we manipulate the integers and
> we will not refer to it again. A similar set-theoretic interpretation can be given to the construction
> of the rational numbers later in this chapter, or the real numbers in the next chapter.

What caught my eye in this note is that Tao suggests we need to apply the Axiom of Replacement twice in order to justify the existence of Z, but Z may be constructed with a single application of replacement: for every (a, b) ∈ N × N, we replace it by a — b and thus get Z. This reasoning seems plausible, but something still feels off about it. Is this argument really correct, and hence a simplification of Tao's idea? Or is there some error in the logic behind it?

Comment: The result of this contruction is that the integers contain the natural numbers $n$ and $-n$ for every natural number $n$ and $0$ if it does not belong to the natural numbers. The construction can however be applied more general : It is the universal way to extend a semigroup to a group in the most natural way.

Comment: So a single application of the Axiom of Replacement is sufficient to construct Z? It looks like the case, because {(c, d) ∈ N × N : (a, b) ∼ (c, d)} can be obtained from N × N by the Axiom of Specification (or directly from replacement as specification can be proven from it). Hence, the existence of a — b seems justified and the construction of Z follows.

Comment: I am not sure but I guess in this case we can actually simplify the construction. Maybe someone else can clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not 100% sure of what Tao has in mind here, but I ***think*** that the application of Replacement which you hypothesize in your question is the *second* application of Replacement. The *first* step is presumably to show that every desired equivalence class is actually a *set* (remember that not every class is necessarily a set).

Granted it's not spelled out in detail, but my *guess* for what Tao has in mind for Step 1 is something like this: For any pair $\langle a, b \rangle$, consider the function which maps every $p \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ either $p \rightarrow p$ (if $p \sim \langle a, b \rangle$) or $p \rightarrow \langle a, b \rangle$ (if ***not*** $p \sim \langle a, b \rangle$). The range of this function is exactly the elements of the desired equivalence class for $\langle a, b \rangle$, and by the Axiom of Replacement there is a *set* containing exactly these elements.

Comment: I actually thought the construction of the equivalence class followed from the Axiom of Specification: starting from the set $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, we build the set of all p such that $p \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and $p \sim \langle a, b \rangle$. But reading your answer, it is reasonable that Tao used Replacement instead.

Comment: Yeah, l think there are probably multiple lines of reasoning to reach that same conclusion. I feel like the argument using Replacement isn’t actually the most intuitive, but it works.

Comment: BTW, Tao has a Wordpress site specifically for this book and he seems to answer a lot of questions from readers there. If you posted the question there (maybe with a link to this Stackexchange question to save some typing), I bet there’s a decent chance he would answer (or maybe even someone has asked the same question there already)